# Help with onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown panel that I have just implemented and need to keep the focus in a textbox after I open the panel. The textbox is not inside the panel but rather below or off the panel on the web page.

Is this possible and if so, how can it be done? I'm using JQuery.

**EDIT:**
To keep the focus in the textbox below this panel, where would I add `$('#test').focus()` in this code?

---

```
var jkpanel={
  controltext: '',
  $mainpanel: null, contentdivheight: 0,

  openclose:function($, speed){
    this.$mainpanel.stop() //stop any animation
    if (this.$mainpanel.attr('openstate')=='closed')
      this.$mainpanel.animate({top: 0}, speed).attr({openstate: 'open'})
    else
      this.$mainpanel.animate({top: -this.contentdivheight+'px'}, speed).attr({openstate: 'closed'})
  },

  init:function(file, height, speed){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      jkpanel.$mainpanel=$('<div id="dropdownpanel"><div class="contentdiv"></div><div class="control">'+jkpanel.controltext+'</div></div>').prependTo('body')
      var $contentdiv=jkpanel.$mainpanel.find('.contentdiv')
      var $controldiv=jkpanel.$mainpanel.find('.control').css({cursor: 'wait'})
      $contentdiv.load(file, '', function($){
        var heightattr=isNaN(parseInt(height)) ? 'auto' : parseInt(height)+'px'
        $contentdiv.css({height: heightattr})
        jkpanel.contentdivheight=parseInt($contentdiv.get(0).offsetHeight)
        jkpanel.$mainpanel.css({top:-jkpanel.contentdivheight+'px', visibility:'visible'}).attr('openstate', 'closed')
        $controldiv.css({cursor:'hand', cursor:'pointer'})
      })
      jkpanel.$mainpanel.click(function(){jkpanel.openclose($, speed)})
    })
  }
}

//Initialize script: jkpanel.init('path_to_content_file', 'height of content DIV in px', animation_duration)
jkpanel.init('panelcontent.htm', '200px', 500);
```

Comment: Is that drop down an Auto complete kind of thing ?

Comment: If you want to display the drop down content dynamically its better to go for jQuery autocomplete plugin. It will take care of everything. Of course nothing is impossible, there might be a way you need to check it out.

Comment: Hey Multiplexer, maybe I didn't explain myself well enough but jkpanel is a dropdown panel that lowers from the top of the screen and is at a 100% width. My problem is that I need to keep focus inside of the textbox which is off the panel, on the web page. When I open the panel, focus in the textbox is lost. When the panel opens, I need the focus to return to the textbox.

Comment: Try to set the focus to the text box when the panel loads. If it is not working then you may need to customize the jkpanel or whatever to not to set the focus on it on load.

Comment: @Multiplexer, I stink at JQuery and Javascript. The plugin is only 33 lines long, would you please tell me where the focus attribute should be added? I'm at a loss here. I can post it if you wouldn't mind having a look

Comment: Of course yes. You might need to add $('#test').focus() in load method.

Comment: Thanks Multiplexer. I've already tried to add the focus just under `load(file, '', function($){` but the whole panel stops working at that point. Am I putting it in the right place?

Comment: Try keeping after the following line.  'jkpanel.$mainpanel.click(function(){jkpanel.openclose($, speed)})'.

Comment: @Multiplexer, thanks for the help. Bryan offered a solution that seems to work a single time then stops. I've already tried adding the focus there but it still won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function takes a callback method as one of its arguments. The callback executes after the animation completes. You could insert your code as the callback to the animation that opens the panel, like so:

```
this.$mainpanel.animate({top: 0}, speed, function() { $('#test').focus(); }).attr({openstate: 'open'})
```

Comment: Bryan, thanks for the example and the explanation. Would I put this code in the load function?

Comment: Bryan, I see where is should go now. Is does put the cursor in the box but if I open the panel a second time, the cursor will not go back into the textbox. It seems like it is only good for a single time. Is there a way to ensure that the txtbox gets the focus no matter the amount of times the panel is opened?

Comment: Hmmm. The callback will execute every time the panel opens, so the textbox should be focused each time as well. Where does the cursor end up on the 2nd try? Maybe something else is going on that steals the focus?

Comment: If I click anywhere outside of the panel before it closes, the focus will return when I open the panel again. If I don't click outside the panel, the focus is only good for one shot.

Comment: Not really sure. I suspect it has something to do with this line: `this.$mainpanel.stop()`. The openclose function is used for both opening and closing, and this line halts any running animations. When that happens, callback methods of the just halted animation don't execute. You can play around with this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PyyCP/) I just created to illustrate. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for all of your help Bryan. It has certainly been a learning experience for me. I'll have a look at your demo now.